# How to resolve BadMethodCallExeption in Laravel (IoC Container)

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, ioc-container

When I add `Route::resource('api', 'ApiController');` to my **app/Http/routes.php**, I get this error:

> BadMethodCallException Method [index] does not exist.

My api controller looks like this:

```
<?php

    class ApiController extends BaseController
    {     
        public function getIndex()
        {
           echo "No Access";
        }
        public function postIndex()
        {
            // content here ...
        }
        public function check_ban($user, $gameBit, $ip)
        {
            // content here ...
        }
        public function check_balance($userid, $gameid, $serverid)
        {
            // content here ...
        }
        public function purchase_item($xml)
        {
            // content here ...
        }
        public function LoginRequest($xml)
        {
            // content here ...
        }
        public function CurrencyRequest($xml)
        {
            // content here ...
        }
        public function ItemPurchaseRequest($xml)
        {
            // content here ...
        }
    }
```

My api should handle out game login request, buying items, ban check and so on, but I get the error described above.

How do I resolve it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using following to declare a `resourceful` route

```
Route::resource('api', 'ApiController');
```

Then let `Laravel` generate methods for you so go to `command prompt/terminal` and run:

```
php artisan controller:make ApiController
```

This will create a `ApiController` resourceful controller in `app/controllers` directory and all the methods will be (Method's skeleton) created. To make sure which method listens to which `URI` and `HTTP` method, run `php artisan routes` from `command prompt/terminal` so you'll get the idea. Read more about [resourceful controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) on `Laravel` website.

If you want to declare your own methods against `HTTP` verbs then create a `RESTful` controller and to create a `RESTful` controller you don't have to run any `artisan` command from `terminal` but declare the route using:

```
Route::controller('api', 'ApiController');
```

Then create methods prefixing with `HTTP` verbs for responding to that verb for example:

```
class ApiController extends BaseController {

    // URL: domain.com/api using GET HTTP method
    public function getIndex()
    {
        //...
    }

    // URL: domain.com/api/profile using POST HTTP method
    public function postProfile()
    {
        //...
    }

    // ...
}
```

If you run `php artisan routes` then you will be able to see all the `URI`s and method mapping. Check [RESTful controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) on `Laravel` website.